# Unable to install java-language-server with mason lsp-zero

Tags: java, linux, neovim, liskov-substitution-principle

I am using lsp-zero which uses mason to install everything but whenever I try to install java-language-server I get the error.

Any help is appreciated.

Whenever i do :LspInstall and choose the first option it shows this

```
\[8/8\] spawn: bash failed with exit code 127 and signal 0.
```

I already tried installing diff versions of java-language-server but didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Unsure if you've resolved this but I'll comment for others searching for answers.

Whenever I run into trouble installing lsp on a new nvim setup, the issue tends to be related to me not having a dependency installed.

Things to try:

- Install/Update Java
- Change the permissions for bash on your zsh (`chmod +x /bin/bash`)
- Check you have all dependencies installed for `java-language-server`
- Use `jdtls` instead